# How To Get Auth ID form user table and grab it for store to other table on database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to get Auth ID from user who has logged in and then use the Auth ID to store on other table

**User_detail Controller**

this is my store function

```php
$data = new ModelUser();
$user= new user();
$data->fill(Auth::user());
$data->id_user = Auth::get('id');     
$data->jenis_kelamin = $request->jenis_kelamin;
$data->no_tlp = $request->no_tlp;   
$data->jurusan = $request->jurusan;
$data->wilayah = $request->wilayah;
$data->save();
return redirect()->route('surveylist');
```

and this is function Login

```php
 public function LoginPost(Request $request)
    {
        $email = $request->email;
        $password = $request->password;

        $data = user::where('email',$email)->first();
        if($data)  //check email apakah ada atau tidak
        {
            if(Hash::check($password,$data->password))
            {
                Session::put('id',$data->id);
                Session::put('full_name',$data->full_name);
                Session::put('email',$data->email);
                Session::put('login',TRUE);

                return redirect('userdt');
            }
            else
            {
                return redirect('index')->with('alert','Password atau Email yang anda masukan salah !!! ' );
            }
        }
    }
```

this is the routes files

```php
Route::get('/index','UserController@show')->name('surevey.index');
Route::get('/logout','UserController@Logout')->name('user.logout');
Route::post('/registerpost','UserController@RegisterPost')->name('user.register');
Route::post('/loginpost','UserController@LoginPost')->name('user.login');

//reward routes
Route::get('/reward','RewardController@index')->name('reward.list');

//profile
Route::put('/editprofile/edit/{id}','UserController@edit')->name('profile.edit');
Route::post('/editprofile/update','UserController@update')->name('profile.update');
Route::get('/userdt',['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'UserController@userdetail'])->name('userdt.show');
Route::post('/userdt/store','UserController@store')->name('userdt.store');

//Survei
Route::get('/createsurvey','SurveyController@show')->name('survey.create');
Route::get('/surveylist','SurveyController@index')->name('survey.list');



Auth::routes();
```

**ModelUser**

```php
protected $fillable = [
    'id_user',
    'jenis_kelamin',
    'no_tlp',
    'jurusan',
    'wilayah'
];

protected $table ='user_detail';

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(user::class);
}
```

and I get error like this

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::fill() must
>   be of the type array, null given, called in
>   E:\Laravel\surevey\app\Http\Controllers\UserController.php on line 110

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `$data->fill(Auth::user());` as you have only single `user_id` field need to set.

Also you can get the current logged in user's id using. `\Auth::user()->id`

So your code would be as follow:

```
$data = new ModelUser();
$data->id_user = \Auth::user()->id;     
$data->jenis_kelamin = $request->jenis_kelamin;
$data->no_tlp = $request->no_tlp;   
$data->jurusan = $request->jurusan;
$data->wilayah = $request->wilayah;
$data->save();
return redirect()->route('surveylist');
```

***Note: Make sure you have included `auth` middleware with your route.***

Like:

```
Route::get('profile', ['middleware' => 'auth', function() {
    // Only authenticated users may enter...
}]);
```

And you have followed the authuntication process carefully.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication

**Edited:**

Your loging should be changed as:

```
public function LoginPost(Request $request)
{
    $email = $request->email;
    $password = $request->password;

    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return redirect()->intended('userdt');
    }

    return redirect('index')->with('alert','Password atau Email yang anda masukan salah !!! ' );
}
```

Comment: @JuMa let me know if it helps!

Comment: i dont know , because i'm not use php artisan Make:auth

Comment: @JuMa make sure you have updated the postLogin function as mentioend in `Edited section`and then add middleware `auth`with your route.

Comment: i have added but still same

Comment: share your routes file.

Comment: after i following the code now when i login has error like this "Undefined variable: data" i fill the authentication passed with session:put

Comment: thanks, that's works , just only add middlewatre auth on routes , thats solve the problem , thanks Vikash

Answer (score 0):

should be `Auth::id()` or `Auth::user()->id` but seems like your `Auth::user()` is returning a null.make sure you sessions, routes are set up properly.

use `Auth::attempt()`to login user

Comment: yes Auth::user() is returning a null , how can i resolve this ??

Comment: did u use `php artisan make:auth` ?

Comment: i didn't use php artisan make:auth :(

Comment: any reason why you didnt use it?  you could have avoided all this if you have used it. everything will be set up by laravel it self login/register.. Authentication

Comment: just because i see a tutorial from one website, and i dont know on the tutorial not use the auth from laravel

Comment: i suggest that you read up on this https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication and get it implemented. it would be the best way

Answer (score 0):

If your reverse one-to-one relationship in the User Model looks like this:

```
 public function detail()
{
    return $this->hasOne(ModelUser::class);
}
```

And you are sure a user is logged in, you could simply do this

```
$data = Auth::user()->detail()->save($request->all());
return redirect()->route('surveylist');
```

Laravel's ORM takes care of the rest.